DISKPART shows unknown status of drive and cannot select it
Backstory:  I made a registry change to show firefox in the quick-pick list of programs that can open a file type.  I restarted my computer but it wouldn't boot.  I haven't been able to boot since and have given up on data recovery.  I bought a new SSD and installed Linux mint 22.  I want to use the 1TB SSD now by formatting it and installing something else on it.  I cannot format it using Linux or Windows. The 1TB SSD was purchased in Aug 2021.
DISKPART> LIST DISK

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Unknown         953 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

The disk you specified is not valid.

There is no disk selected.

DISKPART>

How can I format Disk 1?
I have access to both a Linux and Windows computer.
On linux it shows in lsblk:
adrian@mint:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 238.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 924.8G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0  28.7G  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0  70.7M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1     0B  0 rom  
adrian@mint:~$

but doesn't show in fdisk:
adrian@mint:~$ sudo fdisk -l 
Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SPCC Solid State
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3A0EF88E-3A0C-4A74-870A-416DDD2ED862

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 500117503 500115456 238.5G Linux filesystem
adrian@mint:~$ 

dmesg output:
[16904.084290] ntfs3: 825379 callbacks suppressed
[16904.084295] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084307] print_req_error: 825380 callbacks suppressed
[16904.084308] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084314] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084320] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084324] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084330] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084334] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084340] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084344] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084350] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084354] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084359] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084363] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084370] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084376] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084383] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084387] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084393] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16904.084397] ntfs3: sdb2: failed to read volume at offset 0xb64b7000
[16904.084403] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 6460856 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0


What registry modification did you do exactly?

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\firefox.exe\SupportedTypes - I added a new PDF string.  Turns out it was a terrible idea.

All you did was set the handler for the pdf file extension to Firefox. That absolutely isn’t the reason your system no longer boots

@Ramhound, back in the days of '95, a missing escape backslash in a Registry could make the machine unbootable (e.g. C:\User vs. C:\\User. This I know from sad experience. That said, if the OP cannot access a drive from another OS, then the premise is specious.

SSD's have a finite lifetime. You can try using other tools, such as Windows DiskGenius, to access it, but the SSD seems to have passed on.

@DrMoishePippik - The registry key modified does not have that kind of power. Given the I/O errors I also suspect the SSD not the registry key.

@Ramhound, it's not the specific key. On '95, an unescaped backslash anywhere, even a value, could prevent the whole Registry from loading. '95 was marginally more stable than 3.1, but still relied on cooperative multitasking. Any process that hung stopped everything.

This isn’t that.
